# Swift 3 generic protocol won't take in a dictionary collection

Tags: generics, swift3

I'm trying to solve this problem about inputting any collection into a generic protocol and then searching for the value.

I tried inputting a dictionary collection but I get this error

> error: Generics Gold Challenge.playground:31:33:
>
> error: use of unresolved identifier 'element' if collection[index] == element {

I don't why I'm getting this error or how to correct it?

```
func CheckAnyCollection<T: Collection>(in collection: T, in searchFor: T.Iterator.Element) -> [T.Index] where T.Iterator.Element: Equatable, T.Indices.Iterator.Element == T.Index
    
{
    
    
    var results: [T.Index] = []
    
    for index in collection.indices {
        
        if collection[index] == element {
            
            results.append(index)
        }
        
    }
    
    return results
    
    
}
```

Comment: You don't need a method just for this, it's a one-liner: `zip(c.indices, c).lazy.filter{ $0.1 == element }.map{ $0.0 }`

Comment: I've tried with a dictionary type with the solution provided by -Alexander.   `var result = CheckAnyCollection(in : myDictionary, searchFor: 3)`  **but get this error** `cannot convert value of type Int to expected argument type  '_._Element' `

Comment: Provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Give me a link to a code sharing service, like GitHub gist, pastebin, repl.it or IBM Swift Sandbox

Comment: Here is the GitHub share  [link](https://github.com/aholly38/Generic-Protocol-Collection/commit/497ff1492693410ee0be71487d19829162673940) @Alexander

Comment: So where is the implementation of `CheckAnyCollection(in:for:)`...?

Comment: The CheckAnyCollection is located on lines 62-68, make sure to select **View** located on right hand side of the code box to view entire code. @Alexander

Answer (score 1):

I Think you should try this with minor error fix.

```
 func CheckAnyCollection<T: Collection>(in collection: T,  searchFor element : T.Iterator.Element) -> [T.Index] where T.Iterator.Element: Equatable, T.Indices.Iterator.Element == T.Index

    {


  var results: [T.Index] = []

  for index in collection.indices {

    if collection[index] == element {

      results.append(index)
    }

  }

  return results
}
```

Comment: I've tested the function with the corrections (changed 'in to 'element' )  you've suggested but when I tested it with  dictionary collection I get this error   `cannot convert value of type Int to expected argument type`

Answer (score 0):

Your issue came from using the `Collection.Index` associated type. I'm not exactly sure what's up with it, but I think it's some sort of internal associated type that doesn't do what you would expect. Use `Collection.Indices.Iterator.Element`, instead. Here's your code, patched up

```
func CheckAnyCollection<C: Collection>(
    in c: C,
    for desiredElement: C.Iterator.Element
) -> [C.Indices.Iterator.Element]
where C.Iterator.Element: Equatable
{
    let matchingIndexElementPairs = zip(c.indices, c)
        .lazy
        .filter { (index, element) in element == desiredElement }
        as LazyFilterSequence<Zip2Sequence<C.Indices, C>>
        // annoying type annotation, but necessary to disambiguate

    return matchingIndexElementPairs.map{ $0.0 }
}

print(CheckAnyCollection(in: [1, 2, 3, 2, 1], for: 2)) // => [1, 3]
```

However, there are quite a few issues with this code:

1. Swift methods are named with lowerCamelCase. UpperCamelCase is reserved for types.
2. The name is misleading. "CheckAny" doesn't check anything at all.
3. A function that acts on an instance should be implemented as an instance method to that type in an extension.

Here is how I would write this code:

```
extension Collection where Iterator.Element: Equatable {
    func indices(of desiredElement: Iterator.Element) -> [Indices.Iterator.Element] {
        let matchingIndexElementPairs = zip(self.indices, self)
            .lazy
            .filter { (index, element) in element == desiredElement }
            as LazyFilterSequence<Zip2Sequence<Self.Indices, Self>>
            // annoying type annotation, but necessary to disambiguate

        return matchingIndexElementPairs.map{ $0.0 }
    }
}
```

This approach lets you have a much more natural call site:

```
let indices2 = [1, 2, 3, 2, 1].indices(of: 2)
print(indices2) // => [1, 3]
```

Comment: Thank you, I was able to execute the code but is it possible to use a Dictionary Collection ? @Alexander

Comment: @AlainHolly No, because a dictionary's elements are tuples of type `(key: K, value: V)`, which aren't equatable. That's probably not what you're looking for. Are you trying to get the keys that map to some desired element?

Comment: I realized that I read the Swift exercise incorrectly and that generic collection is what I needed to use.  - Thanks Again

Comment: @AlainHolly "that generic collection is what I needed to use." ... that's what we're using here? What's the exercise?